# Building derived column using Spark transformations

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hadoop2

I got a table record as stated below.

```
Id   Indicator     Date
1       R       2018-01-20
1       R       2018-10-21
1       P       2019-01-22
2       R       2018-02-28
2       P       2018-05-22
2       P       2019-03-05
```

I need to pick the `Id`s that had more than two `R` indicator in the last one year and derive a new column called `Marked_Flag` as `Y` otherwise `N`. So the expected output should look like below,

```
Id  Marked_Flag 
1   Y
2   N
```

So what I did so far, I took the records in a dataset and then again build another dataset from that. The code looks like below.

```
Dataset<row> getIndicators = spark.sql("select id, count(indicator) as indi_count from source group by id having indicator = 'R'");

Dataset<row>getFlag = spark.sql("select id, case when indi_count > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Marked_Flag" from getIndicators");
```

But my lead what this to be done using a single dataset and using Spark transformations. I am pretty new to Spark, any guidance or code snippet on this regard would be highly helpful.

Created two Datasets one to get the aggregation and another used the aggregated value to derive the new column.

```
Dataset<row> getIndicators = spark.sql("select id, count(indicator) as indi_count from source group by id having indicator = 'R'");

Dataset<row>getFlag = spark.sql("select id, case when indi_count > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Marked_Flag" from getIndicators");
```

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofney.png)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWXzE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following. Note that I am using pyspark DataFrame here

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([
[1, "R", "2018-01-20"],
[1, "R", "2018-10-21"],
[1, "P", "2019-01-22"],
[2, "R", "2018-02-28"],
[2, "P", "2018-05-22"],
[2, "P", "2019-03-05"]], ["Id", "Indicator","Date"])

gr = df.filter(F.col("Indicator")=="R").groupBy("Id").agg(F.count("Indicator"))
gr = gr.withColumn("Marked_Flag", F.when(F.col("count(Indicator)") > 1, "Y").otherwise('N')).drop("count(Indicator)")
gr.show()

# +---+-----------+
# | Id|Marked_Flag|
# +---+-----------+
# |  1|          Y|
# |  2|          N|
# +---+-----------+
#
```

Comment: Thank you so much Clock .. I am trying this now. I was looking for something like this. Thanks again!!